# Unauthorised to connect to MYSQL server running in VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I've got an Ubuntu LAMP install running in a VMWare virtual machine. I'm able to connect to the mysql server from inside the VM from the command line, but I'm not able to connect to it from inside the Host OS via the VM's ip address. The error message returned by the mysql server through SQLYog is ...

`Error No. 1130`

`Host 'monolith.home' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

... where 'monolith.home' is the computer name and domain of the Host computer.

So the mysql port appears open, it is just rejecting my connection. Where do I change the kind of access restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you granted a user access from that address?

Try something like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'root'@'%.home' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

and then try login as root from the host.